# Change URL with pushState. Meteor reloads old page

Tags: meteor

I am using `window.history.pushState(name, title, url);` to change the browser URL to let the user know what static url corresponds to an application tab pane.

But Meteor reloads the last real URL (the URL we landed on, before pushState) at each application state change (Meteor reactivity).

How do I change the URL without using a Router.go (that's too heavy for what I am doing, just clicking on a application tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The whole route was triggered again (so reloading the page) because I called a reactive function in onAfterAction. pushState is fine. Meteor also. Duh. :)